# Mystery Word Game: Square Wave with Dots

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

My friends and I were playing a game recently in which, for each round, four of the players were given a word of which they each had to give a rough description to the fifth player. The guessing player would gain a point if they got the word correct.

It came to my turn to be the guesser and the descriptions my friends gave for the word were as follows:

> **Alan:** It's a square with a pair of strips passing through it.
>   **Brenda:** I would say it's more like a repeating square *wave* but one that is crashing.
>   **Catherine:** I wouldn't say it's the waves themselves but it's what's just above, close to land.
>   **Daniel:** I would say they are more like ridges than waves, sometimes interspersed with dots.

Their descriptions seemed completely disparate and I couldn't make sense of them, which worried me quite a bit.

**What word were my friends describing?**
**Please explain each description in your answer.**

Hint (in light of Tom's excellent answer)

> Once the word had been revealed to me, I realised it could also mean something into which I had just gotten myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A second plucky attempt is the word:

> **[fret](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fret)**

It's a square with a pair of strips passing through it.

> A [fret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_(heraldry)#Fixed_subordinaries) which is the heraldic symbol of a mascle (lozenge) with two bendlets (diagonal stripes)
>
>   [image]

I would say it's more like a repeating square wave but one that is crashing.

> A [fret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meander_(art)) pattern has repeated motifs of straight lines and right angles.
>
>   [image]

I wouldn't say it's the waves themselves but it's what's just above, close to land.

> A sea [fret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_(fog)) is a cold sea fog, close to shore.

I would say they are more like ridges than waves, sometimes interspersed with dots.

> A fret is a raised ridge on the neck of a stringed instrument. Marker [dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neck_(music)) are often placed on the face of a guitar's fretboard to indicate harmonic points of the string.

---

First try:  An opening attempt is the word:

> breaker.

A: It's a square with a pair of strips passing through it.

> One symbol for a (circuit) breaker is a square with two lines:
>
>   [image]

B: I would say it's more like a repeating square wave but one that is crashing.

> Another, more complicated one is this [circuit breaker](https://gallery.proficad.com/symbols/electrical-installations/switchgear-and-protective-devices-(ansi)/protective-devices/circuit-breakers/circuit-breaker-with-thermal-overload-device-3P-(form-1).html)
>
>   [image]
>
>   or the percussion hammer for demolishing, which repeatedly crashes on/off against concrete.

C: I wouldn't say it's the waves themselves but it's what's just above, close to land.

> [breaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaker_(reef)) - a raised part of the seabed near the shore, against which waves break.

D: I would say they are more like ridges than waves, sometimes interspersed with dots.

> [breaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wave) - a ridge-like wave near the shore with amplitude at a critical level, popular with surfers which look the dots from a distance?

Comment: This is such a good answer, rather frustratingly not what I was going for. I can't fault you because you've done so well with the explanations. Instead I can offer a +1 and a hint.

Comment: I respectfully suggest that Tom got the right answer and OP's answer is wrong. ;)  (I love when alternate answers fit *this* well; nice job Tom!)

Comment: The new answer is what I was looking for. Well done!